# What is breeze's 1.0.5 metadata schema

Tags: breeze

I just downloaded Breeze js 1.4.4. The problem is that the package comes with metadata examples  in version 1.0.3, yet the library is looking for 1.0.5. Furthermore, the documentation on breeze's site provides metadata examples in 1.0.2. What am I to do?

Comment: Care to make your question a bit clearer? BreezeJS uses standard [OData $metadata][1]. 


  [1]: http://services.odata.org/OData/OData.svc/$metadata

Answer (score 0):

The documentation needs to be updated.  Thanks for catching it.  I'll try to get it fixed this week.

However with the exception of the version number the docs are correct. All of the metadata changes since 1.0.2 have been to add additional capabilities so everything is backward compatible.

If you are exporting and then importing from the same version of Breeze then you will have no issues because the latest version is always used.  In this case, 1.0.5.  If you are creating a Breeze native metadata config then you can either use metadataVersion: 1.0.5 or just omit the metadataVersion property. If omitted then no version checking is performed.

If you are importing old metadata from a Breeze version before 1.0.5, then you will need to either remove the metadataVersion property or set it to 1.0.5.